# Mongoose Splicing a Value from Map of Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have encountered a behaviour that I hope to get an explanation about.

I have a users collection that has a uid, and a Map of Array field in its schema.

```
userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uid: {type: String, unique: true},
    words: {type: Map, of: Array}
})
```

I want to remove a single value from the array of some key, lets say I have a user:

```
{
uid: "3", 
words: {
   "example" -> ['one', 'two', 'three'] 
    }
}
```

and I want to remove the value 'two' from example.

to do this what I did was:

```
deleteValue = (id, key, value, callback) => {
 userModel.findOne({ uid: id }, (err, user) => { 
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        if (user.words.has(key)) {
            const valuesArray = user.words.get(key);
            const indexOfValue = valuesArray.indexOf(value);

            if (indexOfValue >= 0) {
                valuesArray.splice(indexOfValue, 1);
                user.words.set(key, valuesArray);
                
                user.save().then(() => callback("Deleted " + value + " From " + key));
            }
        }
        else {
            callback("Key not found");
        }

    });
}
```

However the user in the DB never changed, I logged the new valuesArray, and it did change, I logged the returned Promise from user.save, and it seemed to be the user without the value, and I found that the only way to fix it was to work on a copy of the valuesArray:

```
// const valuesArray = user.words.get(key);
const valuesArray = [...user.words.get(key)];
```

Can someone explain why it didn't save the user without the spliced value when I didn't work on a copy of the array? even though it looked like it did save a user without the value.

Thank you.

Comment: Try a `filter` and save the modified array

Comment: Try https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html.